# How to do basic optimisation using loco

Tags: optimization, clojure, constraint-programming

I am trying to do a basic example of optimisation using [loco](https://github.com/aengelberg/loco).

I have a vector of costs the index of which corresponds to the integer value of a number of slots and would like to minimize the sum of the costs for a distinct subset of the slots.

Please see my attempt below, which fails to work because there is no "link" between the picked slots and the costs.

```
(def costs [10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40 10 10])

(let [slot-vars (for [i (range 5)] ($in [:slot i] 1 10))
      cost-vars (for [i (range 10)] ($in [:cost i] 10 40))]
  (solution
   (concat
    slot-vars
    cost-vars
    [($distinct (for [i (range 5)] [:slot i]))]
    (for [i (range 5)]
      ($= [:cost i] (get costs i))))
   :minimize (apply $+ (for [i (range 5)] [:slot i]))))
```

Comment: This sounds like a minimize knapsack problem.

You can do a maximise, but not a minimise. Would possibly have to deal with the choco library directly to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm not entirely sure I understand the point of this problem, because clearly the solution is to just take the 5 smallest values in the list.  But if you want to make loco do it, I agree that the knapsack constraint is a handy tool for this.  Contrary to what Mike said in his comment, I don't see any obstacle to using knapsack for minimization.  Let the weights all be 1, and enforce that the weights add up to 5 in order to select 5 out of the 10 slots.  I've used the variable `[:include i]` to indicate whether slot i should be included in the subset (1 for true and 0 for false).  We want to minimize the dot product of the vector of :include variables and the cost vector.

```
(def costs [10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40 10 10])
(def weights (repeat 10 1))

(def include-vars (for [i (range 10)] [:include i]))
(def include-constraints (for [i (range 10)] ($in [:include i] 0 1)))

(def model
  (concat
   include-constraints
   [($knapsack weights costs include-vars 5 :total)
    ($in :total 0 (apply + costs))]))

(solution model :minimize :total)
```

The result is:

```
{[:include 4] 0, [:include 6] 0, [:include 9] 1, [:include 1] 1, [:include 3] 0, [:include 8] 1, :total 60, [:include 0] 1, [:include 7] 0, [:include 2] 1, [:include 5] 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The example is just illustrative, In my real use case the vars will be subject to numerous other constraints.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer, but I hope it might help point in a direction that might help. It sounds like a knapsack problem?

You can find the max with:

```
(def slots (for [i (range 10)] (keyword (str "slot-" i))))

(solution
   (concat
    (for [s slots] ($in s 0 1))
    [($in :total-weight 10 60)
     ($in :total-value 5 5)
     ($knapsack [10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40 10 10]
                (repeat 10 1)
                slots :total-weight :total-value)]))
```

Assuming you can only have 5 slots.

Could possibly write a minimising version by looking at the source code and working with the Choco library directly?

Check the source of the loco [knapsack](https://github.com/aengelberg/loco/blob/57206cffb89a7c7b4c213c192a76f4aa7967a0b8/src/loco/constraints.clj#L645) function.